# listen component for change @Input() value in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

hi i have this component . in this component i have `@Input() userId: number[] = [];` for send list of id to this component .

i use this component in other component , for example i use it in the `news` component :

```
<kt-user-post-list-select [userId]="noWriterIdList" (selectedUserId)="getSelectionUserList($event)">
</kt-user-post-list-select>
```

when i send a request to server for add news it return to me list of id : `[1,2,3]` and then i must send that ids to the `kt-user-post-list-select` with this `[userId]="noWriterIdList"` , **But i have Problem :** i need when pass the list to this component it track the changes and execute this function :

```
    validateUSerIsWriter(ids: number[]): void {
    for (let id = 0; id < ids.length; id++) {
        let user = this.users.find(x => x.userId = id);
        if (user != null) {
            user.isDeleted = true;

        }
    }
}
```

but it dosent any work .

**how can i solve this problem ???**

Comment: You can use Subject and then use next  method to send newly arrived data!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale and how can i tell to that for execute this function : `validateUSerIsWriter()`

Comment: while using subjectBehaviour there is one useful method called subscribe which you need to call and in that function you can call this method

Comment: If you provide stackblitz demo with above code will help you!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xmu9eb

Comment: Link example is broken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways

1. Use `ngOnChanges` hook inside `kt-user-post-list-select` component. So you can listen for new Ids and execute the function `validateUSerIsWriter`. But remember, this comes with a cost of compromising performance.
2. Use `Subject` to subscribe for the newIds, and execute the function `validateUSerIsWriter`. In this case you don't need `@Input` decorator. Please refer this simple example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-subject-observable